# Console app on OS X crashes at startup

Tags: macos, console

Console app osx 10.8.2 crashes at startup. Posted in alarm log, but it closes so fast that I do not have time to read it. What could be the reason? How to treat?

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on.  What is this console app that's crashing?  How did you invoke it?  If you start it from the shell, do you see any output to that shell window?

Comment: Utility console.app.

Comment: Well, that narrows it down.  How many of those could there be?

Comment: @NicoleHamilton: uhm.  Just one.  Console.app lives in the Utilities folder on OS X and comes with the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

I had to delete these files:

```
/Users/YourUserName/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Console.LSSharedFileList.plist
/Users/YourUserName/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Console.plist     
/Users/YourUserName/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist
```

After reboot, it was fine